# MATLAB plot- Filtering data before plotting

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure

I have a 90x2 matrix `a` where a(:,1) is the x and a(:,2) is the y.

I want to plot only values where y is greater than BOOM. How can I do that?

Currently I have

```
plot(a(:,1),a(:,2));
```

One more thing, how can I display the numbers in full and not `num*10^4`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard approach is to make a mask with `find`. You would do that first

```
mask = find(a(:,2) > BOOM);
```

the mask will be a list of index positions where the second column exceeded the BOOM threshold. You can use it to select only those entries from the row ordering

```
plot(a(mask,1), a(mask,2))
```

You could also make a logical mask, it works much the same way and is sometimes more convenient.

As for the display you can try

```
format short
```

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your second question, do you want to display the number in full on the console?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
plot (a(a(:,2)>BOOM,1),a(a(:,2)>BOOM,2));
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', num2cell(get(gca, 'YTick')))
```